# Image redirect in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used the image redirect rule in .htaccess it is working but subdomain images do not show.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?sitename [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?sitename.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /image_forward.php?image=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

Above Rewrite condition work properly but when i open subdomain i.e.(name.sitename.com) images are not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your subdomain as one of the conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?subdomain.sitename [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?sitename [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?sitename.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /image_forward.php?image=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

WHere "subdomain.sitename" is your subdomain.